# android edittext add square border how to make it square?

Tags: android, android-edittext

i want to create edittext with square border in android xml
this is my edittext and the drawable added to it

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/codeFirst"
    android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
    android:lines="2"/>
```

this is the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<stroke android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/colorsubtext" />
<padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
  </shape>
```

the edittext look like rectangle rotated, i need to make it square one, all border side are equal

Answer (score 0):

If you want a square border on the `edittext`, then you have to specify the `width` and `height` instead of using `wrap_content`.

`android:layout_width="100dp"`

`android:layout_height="100dp"`

Answer (score -1):

you can follow this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/color_primary" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />

</shape>
```